# How to overwrite Excel destination in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have created a package to fetch data from two SQL Server tables, and using merge join combined this data, then stored the result into an Excel destination.

The first time it works fine. The second time it stores repeated data in the Excel file.

How do I overwrite the Excel file rows?

Comment: Do You want to always create new file, or: insert new rows, delete non-existing rows and update existing rows in destination excel?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, Possible!

Here is the solution:

First go to your Excel Destination Click to New Button next to Name of Excel Sheet, copy the DML query inside.
Then put an Execute SQL Task into your Control Flow and connect it to your data flow that contains Excel destination. Set the Connection Type To Excel, Set the Connection to your Excel Destination's Excel Connection Manager, go to SQL Statement and type :

```
Drop TABLE `put the name of the sheet in the excel query you just copied`
Go
```

finally paste the query after it.

It is all you need to do to solve the problem.

You can refer to this link for a complete info:
http://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @GergoErdosi, the answer modified accordingly.

Comment: @GergoErdosi, I answered the question and it works for sure. However, Instead of being rewarded I have lost points! It is not fair, is it? :)

Comment: @Sahand, Nice, although I had to use syntax like DROP TABLE [mySheet$] . +1

Comment: It works fine if the file realy exists, But what regarding to the first time? I got exception "Table 'MY TABLE NAME' does not exist."

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Possible!

Using SSIS we can solve this problem:

first of all, crate an Excel format file (Structure Format using **Excel Connection Manager**) at one location as a template file. Then create a copy of that excel file using **FILE SYSTEM TASK** in another location and make sure that SET **OverwriteDestination=True**. Finally, using a **data flow task**, insert data into the new copied file. whenever we want insert data, it will create a copy of the template excel file and then load the data.

[image]

Comment: Excellent suggestion - Thinking outside the box! Thank you manoj.

Comment: @manoj, I created an OLE DB Connection and an Excel Connection Manager to write data into an Excel file. Then, I created a File System task to create a Copy of that Excel File and set Is-Overwrite=True. Now, if I run the Data Flow Task, it keeps appending the data into the original Excel File and the File System Task copies that File to a new File in a separate location.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the Excel connection manager does not have a setting that allows overwriting the data. You'll need to set up some file manipulation using the File System Task in the Control Flow.

There are several possibilities, here's one of them. You can create a template file (which just contains the sheet with the header) and prior to the Data Flow Transformation a File System Task copies it over the previously exported file.

[The File System Task (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140185.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For Excel it will append data. There is no such option available for overwriting data.

You have to delete and recreate the file through the File System task.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CSV file with flat-file connection manager would serve your purpose of overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was using File System Tasks to delete and recreate the Excel files from a template.

What I was trying to do was to send every employee a report with Excel attachment in the same format but different data. In a foreach container for each employee, I get the required data, create an Excel file and send a mail with the Excel file attached.

I first:

1. Create an Excel template (manually)
2. Create an original Excel file to be used (manually)

Then in the foreach container:

3. Delete the original file (SSIS File System Task )
4. Copy the template as the original file (SSIS File System Task)
5. Get the data from SQL Server and write them to the original file (SSIS Data Flow Task)
6. Send the mail (SSIS -> SQL Stored Procedure)